# I need to sum up thousands of histograms from one directory

Tags: c++, macros, histogram, root-framework, tcanvas

I have a directory `Processed_Data` with thousands of `hists*****_blinded.root` files. Each `hists*****_blinded.root` contains around 15 graphs and histograms in it. My goal is just to overlap 1 specific histogram `sc*****` from each file to get the final histogram `finalhists_blinded.root` which will represent all of those overlapped together.

I have tried the following macro:

```
void final()
{
   TCanvas *time = new TCanvas("c1","overlap" ,600,1000);
   time ->Divide(1,1);
   time ->cd(1);

   TH1F *h1 = new TH1F("h1","time" ,4096,0,4096);
   ifstream in;
   Float_t t;
   Int_t nlines= 0;
   in.open("Processed_Data", ios::in);
   while (1) {
      in >> t;
      if (!in.good()) break;
      h1->Fill(t);
      nlines++;
   }
   in.close();
```

But I get the blank canvas at the end. The idea is to run each `hists` file through the code and add each one by one.

As a result, I want to see all those `sc*****` histograms overlapping so that the spikes in each of them will create a pattern in a `finalhists_blinded.root` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't be that complicated, try this:

```
void overlap()
{
        TCanvas *time = new TCanvas("c1", "overlap", 0, 0, 800, 600);

        const char* histoname = "sc";

        const int NFiles = 100000;
        for (int fileNumber = 0; fileNumber < NFiles; fileNumber++)
        {
                TFile* myFile = TFile::Open(Form("Processed_Data/hists%i_blinded.root", fileNumber));
                if (!myFile)
                {
                        printf("Nope, no such file!\n");
                        return;
                }
                TH1* h1 = (TH1*)myFile->Get(histoname);
                if (!h1)
                {
                        printf("Nope, no such histogram!\n");
                        return;
                }
                h1->SetDirectory(gROOT);
                h1->Draw("same");
                myFile->Close();
        }
}
```

It loops over all `Processed_Data/histsXXXXXi_blinded.root` files (given their names are `Processed_Data/hists0_blinded.root`, `Processed_Data/hists1_blinded.root`, `Processed_Data/hists2_blinded.root`, ..., `Processed_Data/hists99998_blinded.root`, `Processed_Data/hists99999_blinded.root`), opens each of them, grabs a 1D `sc` histogram, adds it to the canvas, closes the file and moves to the next file.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work. So I have created a `sample` directory. It contains `hists9013_blinded.root` ... `hists9022_blinded.root`. I have also changed `const int NFiles = 10` and `int fileNumber = 9013`. I still have a blank canvas.

Comment: From a [more recent question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946349/overlap-hundresds-of-histograms-macro-question) I figured you have a zero pre-pending a number in the file name if the number is < 10000. In that case, please replace the line with the `TFile` constructor with `TFile* myFile = TFile::Open(Form("Processed_Data/hists%0i_blinded.root", fileNumber));`. Also, did you replace the `const char* histoname = "sc";` with the correct histogram name? I have a working setup with just 3-4 files, I can share it with you if needed.

Comment: I have just added an answer to [that recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56946349/overlap-hundresds-of-histograms-macro-question) I was talking about. If it still does not work with the newest changes, let's continue the discussion over there.